# System.out.println is not printing output

Tags: java

Here is my code to find even Fibonacci numbers and to add them:

```
 package a;
 import java.util.*;

public class A {

 //this about finding Even Fibonacci numbers and adding them to sum.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    int[] n = new int[t];
    int[] nn = new int[t];
    int i,j,sum;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        n[a0] = in.nextInt();            
    }
    nn[0]=1;
    for(i = 0 ; i<t;i++){
        sum = 0;
        for(j= 1;j<n[i];j++){                
            nn[j] = j+nn[j-1];
            if(nn[j]%2==0)
                {
                sum += nn[j];
                }
            }            
        System.out.println(sum); //this is not printing the output
    }
}
}
```

Sample Input

2
10
100

Sample Output

10
44

The problem is that this line `System.out.println(sum);` is not printing anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: No... it's not. Good observation.

Comment: that probably means the loop never goes through an iteration. What are you passing in as the `int t`?

Comment: What makes you think it should print something? Did you provide all necessary values? It looks like your code may be waiting for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have

```
for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
    n[a0] = in.nextInt();            
}
```

The problem is that the program is waiting for you to enter `t` integers. I don't know what values you want there, but change it to something more like this

```
for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
    n[a0] = 0;//But instead of 0 the actual number that you want to set for the value.            
}
```

I hope you find this helpful!

Comment: If you downvote, please leave a comment why. This helps to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see a problem here. Just took the code, compiled and executed it. After specifying the value for t and also providing t input values, I saw an output on the console.

```
stefan@linux-3047:~$ java A
5 (t)
1 (1st of 5 values)
2 (2nd of 5 values)
3 (3rd of 5 values) 
4 (4th of 5 values) 
5 (5th of 5 values) 
0 (System.out.println)
2 (System.out.println)
6 (System.out.println)
6 (System.out.println)
6 (System.out.println)
```

Comment: when i try it in my netbeans it is not showing any output

Comment: and if you try on the console?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple problems exist here.

One error at line 25 if the `t for example is 5`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at application.A.main(A.java:25)
```

---

Added some `System.out.println(...)` to see how you can fix it cause i don't know the code you want to add:

package application;

```
import java.util.*;

public class A {

    // This about finding Even Fibonacci numbers and adding them to sum.

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter a number below:\n");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered..." + t+"\n");

        // Arrays
        int[] n = new int[t];
        int[] nn = new int[t];
        int i, j, sum;

        // First For Loop
        for (int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number a0..");
            n[a0] = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("You entered ao=:" + a0+"\n");
        }
        nn[0] = 1;

        // Second For Loop
        for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
            sum = 0;
            for (j = 1; j < n[i]; j++) {
                nn[j] = j + nn[j - 1];
                if (nn[j] % 2 == 0) {
                    sum += nn[j];
                }
            }

            // this is not printing the output
            System.out.println("Sum is:="+sum); 
        }
    }
}
```